# Backup specific tables in AWS RDS Postgres Instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have two databases on Amazon RDS, both Postgres. Database 1 and 2

I need to restore an instance from a snapshot of Database 1 for my Staging environment. (Database 2 is my current Staging DB).

However, I want the data from a few of the tables in Database 2 to overwrite the tables in the newly restored snapshot. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` have the option to filter only certain tables. Use that.

Answer (score 6):

When restoring RDS from a Snapshot, a new database instance is created. If you only wish to copy a portion of the snapshot:

- **Restore** the snapshot to a new (temporary) database
- Connect to the new database and **dump** the desired tables using `pg_dump`
- Connect to your staging server and **restore** the tables using `pg_restore` (most probably deleting any matching existing tables first)
- **Delete** the temporary database

`pg_dump` actually outputs SQL commands that are then used to recreate tables and restore data. Look at the content of a dump to understand how the restore process actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this still works for someone else.

With my team, we faced a similar issue. We also had 2 Postgres databases and we also just needed to backup some tables from db1 to db2.

What we did is use a lambda function using Python (from AWS lambda ofc) that connected to both databases and validates if `db1.table1` has the same data as `db2.table1`, if not, then the lambda function should write the missing data from `db1.table1` into `db2.table1`. The approach of using lambda was because we wanted to automate the process due to the main DB (let's say `db1`) is constantly being updated. In addition, it allowed us to only back up our desired tables (let's say 3 tables out of 10), instead of backing up the whole database.

Note: Maybe you want to do these writes using temporary tables to avoid issues with any constraints you have in your tables.